# Android 7.0 Dont Show Multiple Permission Request

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

im trying to show multiple permission request on Android 7.0

This code working with no problem on Android sdk 23.

SDK 24 showing one time the request, if i touch allow or denied button, this code working one time and Don't show other request.

Code is here;

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            }

            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, 1);
            }

            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Rather than have three `requestPermissions()` calls, have *one* `requestPermissions()` calls, for the particular mix of permissions that you need. I use a utility `netPermissions()` method to simplify this, such as in [this sample activity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Permissions/tutorial/finish/RuntimePermTutorial/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/perm/tutorial/MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            boolean flag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(permissions[i]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (flag) {
                requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for best solution!

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if permission is already granted and if not granted then ask for permission using below code.

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS};

    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
```

Once permissions are granted, you can execute below code to check whether a particular permission was granted or denied

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case PERMISSION_ALL: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                } else {

                }

                if (grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                } else {

                }

                if (grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                } else {

                }

                if (grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                } else {

                }

                if (grantResults[4] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                } else {

                }


            } else {

                //All permission denied

            }
            runAfterPermissionGranted();

            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```