# Multiple consecutive permission requests not working

Tags: android, security, android-permissions, android-security, runtime-permissions

Calling `ActivityCompat.requestPermission()` with *dangerous* permission requests, multiple times consecutively, causes only the first request to prompt the user with permission-grant dialog. Consider the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_recorder);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        Log.i("Permissions: ", "Requesting audio input --> requestCode: 300");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 300);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        Log.i("Permissions: ", "Requesting read contacts --> requestCode: 200");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 200);
    }

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    Log.i("Permissions: ", String.format("requestCode: %d --> permissions array length: %d", requestCode, permissions.length));
    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
        Log.i("Permissions: ", String.format(
                "%s --> %s", permissions[i],
                grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
    }
}
```

The grant permission system dialog only appears for the first request. Then regardless of whether the user accepts/denies the request, the subsequent request (i.e. for read contacts in this case) doesn't trigger a system dialog. **Why does this happen?**

**Note:** all requests were declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

The following are the logs: (here, I selected **Allow** in audio-input permission system dialog. Selecting **Deny** only replaces the `true` with a `false` in the last log line - rest of the log stays the same)

```
2020-02-17 18:20:01.377 12876-12876/demoapp I/Permissions:: Requesting audio input --> requestCode: 300
2020-02-17 18:20:01.397 12876-12876/demoapp I/Permissions:: Requesting read contacts --> requestCode: 200
2020-02-17 18:20:01.398 12876-12876/demoapp I/Permissions:: requestCode: 200 --> permissions array length: 0
2020-02-17 18:20:13.917 12876-12876/demoapp I/Permissions:: requestCode: 300 --> permissions array length: 1
2020-02-17 18:20:13.917 12876-12876/demoapp I/Permissions:: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO --> true
```

**My Research:** The documentation for `ActivityCompat.onRequestPermissionsResult()` says:

> Callback for the result from requesting permissions. This method is invoked for every call on ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, String[], int).
>
> **Note:** It is possible that the permissions request interaction with the user is interrupted. In this case you will receive empty permissions and results arrays which should be treated as a cancellation.

But the documentation doesn't say anything about **what kind of interruptions**. And assuming "*these interruptions*" are the reason for the logged behavior, **what is causing those interruptions with the above code** - given that the app is very basic (all it does is startup and asks the user for permissions).

**PS:** I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803825/android-7-0-dont-show-multiple-permission-request), but the answer only suggests asking all the required permissions once in a single call to `ActivityCompat.requestPermission()`, which is fine. But **I want to know why doesn't the above method work?** or **What could be the possible interruptions?**.

Comment: Call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` once, with whatever permissions that you need (`RECORD_AUDIO`, `READ_CONTACTS`, or both).

Comment: @CommonsWare - Yeah, that does work, but why doesn't the above method (of consecutive separate requests) work?

Comment: Under the covers, `requestPermissions()` does what amounts to a `startActivityForResult()`. That's not designed for multiple invocations in succession.